# In Python how to fetch 10 characters after a specific string in a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to read input form a text file which has around 1000 lines of data like:

```
SMSfrom+447919311433to+408640236167
Phonecallfrom+652578614377to+173972991459
```

Output desired:

```
+447919311433
```

I wanted to fetch all UK phone numbers from the text file and am trying to fetch 10 charecters after searching the string +44 in the file.I am using python 2.7.5 .Please help.

Comment: This seems pretty simple. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ what is 'too broad' about the question, seems pretty straightforward to me. Yes, they haven't tried anything but its still clear...

Comment: @JoeIddon "Too broad" is a standin for "low effort question".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `txt` file called `log.txt`, with contents:

```
SMSfrom+447919311433to+408640236167
Phonecallfrom+652578614377to+173972991459
```

we can open the `file` for reading with:

```
open("log.txt", "r")
```

Then, we can `loop` through each `line` in the file and try and extract the data you want.

### `regular expression` solution:

To extract the data from a `line`, we can use  a `regular expression`. If you have never encountered these before, they are ways of extracting data from a `string` using a `pattern` which consists of different special characters.

So that we can pickup `2` UK phone numbers in one line, we will use the `re.findall` function on the line. I created the following `pattern` to pickup all UK phone numbers:

```
\+44\d{10}
```

It works by searching for the `string` `'+44'` with an escaping `'\'` on the `'+'` special character, and then taking `10` `digits` after that with `\d{10}` (the `\d` means a digit and the `{10}` means `10` of them).

We can then put this `expression` inside a `loop` which will add each phone number to a `list`. As `re.findall` returns a list as well, we need to concatenate these `lists` instead of `appending`. We do this with the `'+'` operand (or more simply with `+=`).

Making the code that will pickup **all** UK phone numbers in the `file`:

```
import re

numbers = []
with open("log.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers += re.findall("\+44\d{10}", line)
```

which for your `2` line  `file` in the question, only gives one phone number in `numbers`:

```
['+447919311433']
```

### `if-statement` solution:

**this solution will NOT pickup the second UK phone number if it is from a UK and to a UK number as pointed out by Nick as `index()` returns only the first occurrence**

To extract the data from a line, we must first test `if` the `string`: `'+44'` is in the `line` and, if it is, we want to find the `index` of `'+44'` in the `line` and add the `10` characters after that `index` to a `list` of numbers (note that the `.index()` method `returns` the index of the start of the `string`, so we need to take `13` (`10` + `3` for `'+44'`) characters after the index).

The code for this would look like:

```
numbers = []
with open("log.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if '+44' in line:
            start = line.index('+44')
            numbers.append(line[start:start+13])
```

which will add to the list: `numbers`, which will finish with contents:

```
['+447919311433']
```

Obviously, if you used your `1000` lined `txt` file, then this `list` would be much longer!

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if a UK number messaged a UK number? This immediately won't work.

Comment: @NickA I have now added  a solution that will not have this problem with a `regex`... **:)**

Answer (score 0):

String with phone numbers:

```
string="+440123456789+341234567890+442345678901+443456789012"
```

You apply this algorithm to it:

```
for i in range(0,len(string)):
    if string[i] == "+" and string[i+1] == "4" and string[i+2] == "4":
        number = string[i:i+13]
        print(number)
```